# How to subtract two calculated fields from the same table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT   *, 
         SUM(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee) AS totalcost, 
         customerpaid                           AS totalrevenue, 
         (totalcost - totalrevenue)             AS profit 
FROM     tblsales 
GROUP BY orderno 
HAVING   " . $having . " 
ORDER BY $sort $order 
LIMIT    $offset,$rows
```

If I omit `(totalcost - totalrevenue) as profit` the query works fine. How could I calculate PROFIT in the same query using totalcost and totalrevenue?

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is that you have to repeat the expressions:

```
select *, sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee) as totalcost
       customerpaid as totalrevenue,
       (sum(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee) - customerpaid) as profit
from tblsales
group by orderno
having " . $having . "
order by $sort $order
limit $offset, $rows;
```

You are not allowed to use a column alias in the same `select` where it is defined.

And, your query looks weird.  Any query that has `select *` and `group by` is suspect.  You have many columns (presumably) whose value will come from an indeterminate row for each group.  You should explicitly list the columns in general, but you should especially do so for a `group by`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. May I ask why should I use column names explicitly? I mean what's the logic behind.

Comment: @BubbaYakoza . . . Do you understand what `group by` does?  Having columns in the `select` that are not in the `group by` list generally does not make sense.  Perhaps the documentation on the extension will help:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this
SELECT * , (totalcost - totalrevenue) AS profit FROM(
SELECT   *, 
         SUM(price+shipping+paypalfee+storefee) AS totalcost, 
         customerpaid                           AS totalrevenue,

FROM     tblsales 
GROUP BY orderno 
HAVING   " . $having . " 
ORDER BY $sort $order )
LIMIT    $offset,$rows